# How can I get have_posts() to look for posts in all languages?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

We have a multilingual site with posts in many different languages. How can I display excerpts of all of an author's posts in all of the languages they have published in? [have_posts()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/have_posts/) seems to only pull from the site's default language. Here's what I currently have in a custom author.php template:

```
<?php $curauth = (isset($_GET['author_name'])) ? get_user_by('slug', $author_name) : get_userdata(intval($author)); ?>
...

<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
        <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>                       
            <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'index' ); ?>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
            <?php else : ?>
        <p><i><?php esc_html_e( 'This person has not authored any articles.' ); ?></i></p>
        <?php endif; ?>
```

A var_dump for an author who only published in French, for example, returns FALSE.

I have also tried using get_posts(), but as you can see, this requires specifying the language, and I want to be able to pull posts in ANY language. The excerpting on this also isn't working correctly.

```
    <?php 
                $args = array( 'post_type' => 'post', 'order' => 'DESC', 'author' => $curauth->ID, 'lang' => 'fr', 'post_status' => 'publish');
                $posts = get_posts($args);
                if (!empty($posts)) {
                    foreach($posts as $post => $post_val){ ?>
                        <h1 class="entry-title textcenter-xs"><?php echo $post_val->post_title ?></h1>
                    <?php
                        echo wp_trim_excerpt($post_val->post_content); //This is returning ALL the content, not the excerpt
                    }
                } 
                ?>
```

I'm still new to php, so any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

by **removing** the `'lang' => 'fr'` parameter you should get a loop that display all post available. gl.